# Force a collection of unknown number of points to be a polygon

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I am working with point clusters and want to create the rough shape of the cluster in the form of a polygon using `ST_ConvexHull()`. I'm having problems with single outliers though, as they don't convert to a polygon but to a `POINT`:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(point))) ...

POLYGON((13.01741532 52.40118295,13.382100866593 52.516280103729, ...))
POINT(12.5 51.5)
```

Is there a way to force small geometries (single or double points) into a polygon? I want to simplify the subsequent processing by guaranteeing polygons; accuracy is not a high priority in this case, making a minimal triangle out of a single point is fine, even if not exact.

Comment: may be you could buffer them?

Comment: I suppose that's a way, but that may produce unnecessarily complex geometries. I'd be a lot happier with a minimal bounding triangle. :)

Comment: A "minimal bounding triangle" would be a point or a line segment. @iant is correct: any solution would be a *prima facie* buffer so the only questions are what shape that buffer should have and how large it ought to be.

Comment: OK, I guess buffering it is then. Anyone care to put this into an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ST_ConvexHull can return Points, Linestrings, or Polygons so you'll need to buffer anything that isn't a polygon.  As @whuber states, the exact buffering is up to you.  The following query illustrates the general idea.

```
WITH pts(pt, grp) AS (
  VALUES
   -- single point
  (ST_MakePoint(1,1), 1),
   -- two points
   (ST_MakePoint(1,1), 2),
   (ST_MakePoint(1,2), 2),
   -- linear points - makes a linestring
   (ST_MakePoint(1,1), 3),
   (ST_MakePoint(1,2), 3),
   (ST_MakePoint(1,3), 3),
   -- expected case
   (ST_MakePoint(1,1), 4),
   (ST_MakePoint(1,2), 4),
   (ST_MakePoint(2,1), 4)
), hulls AS (
  SELECT ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(pt)) AS hull
  FROM pts
  GROUP BY grp
)
SELECT
  ST_GeometryType(hull) AS hull_type,
  ST_AsText(hull) AS hull,
  ST_AsText(
  CASE
    WHEN ST_GeometryType(hull) = 'ST_Polygon' THEN hull
    ELSE ST_Buffer(hull, 0.01)
  END) AS always_polygon
FROM hulls;
```